# .htaccess SEO urls and redirecting urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am a php programmer but not really an expert with apache server related stuff. I have to re do a project where I need to have SEO urls which would be done in a separate directory structure different from the current one. I would also have to convert existing urls from the current directory structure to the new directory structure thus

> http://path.com/to/?the=page would need to be redirected to http://path.com/new/path/page

There would be instances where the new directory structure may not contain the necessary paths of the current one so I would need those to default to its original url. I've been reading up on the whole Mod_Rewrite bit so I have a gist of what's all about

I'm looking for some advice on the best approaches to handle this and if their any frameworks that ONLY specifically deal with or handle this sort of mechanism

Comment: Provide more examples of old and new URIs to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^the=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^to/?$ /new/path/%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

You can vary whatever paths or query string to match the redirect that you want.

Comment: @Kendall Then you have to group in parentheses and backreference like in the query string, or describe in detail exactly the many-to-many mapping

Comment: Ok maybe many to many might not have been the best phrase...There can be an instant where an old uri may not exists in the new url so I kind of need a catch all so if it exists it goes to the new url if not then it defaults to something...I have a feeling though this may be a PHP logic to construct

Comment: @Kendall you can't do anything that complicated using mod_rewrite, there's really not much logic you can employ. The best thing you can do is use clever regular expressions to match specific parts of the URI